# "which usually is the case for ..." or "which is usually the case for ..."

Tags: grammar

Which of the variants is more correct in (American) English, "which usually is the case for ..." or "which is usually the case for ..."? For example

> Some people don't speak perfect English, which (usually is | is usually) the case for me.

The Google search seems to return twice as many results for the first variant, but the second one feels bit more easy to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AmE, I would say *..., which is usually the case* is used more often than the first example, as it flows more readily.

> Gas furnaces produce less particulate matter than oil furnaces when both are maintained infrequently, which is usually the case for residential ... (NYT)
>   ...which is usually the case for the major traded currencies... (WSJ)
>   His ball striking is very crisp which is usually the case for him when he's... (USA Today)

Answer (score 0):

The second one sounds a bit more natural. The first one is correct, but you'll have to write it this way: "which, usually, is the case for..."

Comment: I'm not sure you need the commas as you've written above. It appears that *usually* is serving as an adverb modifying *is*. One wouldn't write *it, commonly, is understood to mean...*. One might, however, use a comma before *which*, depending on the sentence, e.g. *even if you are the most successful and if you meet your objectives, which usually is the case for...*

Comment: Right, maybe it isn't necessary, but I think it reads better if you put commas before and after "usually".

Comment: I tend to use commas only when necessary to aid comprehension or readability of a sentence, and as such would avoid them in the manner you describe, especially since *which usually* is *usually* preceded by a comma already (see OP's example). :)

Comment: At any rate, I would rephrase his sentence to "Some people don't speak perfect English, which is my case." I don't see any reason why "usually" should be there.